# how to install the greasemonkey in google chrome / opera / midori?

Tags: google-chrome, opera

anyidea how to install its on its ? in google chrome / opera / midori ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Google Chrome you don't need to install a Greasemonkey extension as you do on Firefox, but if you click on a Greasemonkey script you will automatically have the option to install it.